# Find out type of function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have two types in TypeScript, for example:

```
type Function1 = (text: string) => number
type Function2 = (count: number) => string
```

Next, I have some function:

```
const myFunction = (text: string) => 7 // type Function1
```

How to find out type of function (`Function1` or `Function2`)?

```
if (myFunction instanceof Function1) // Not working.
if ('property' in myFunction) // ...?
```

Comment: Ask yourself how you would accomplish something like this in pure JavaScript at runtime, and then recall that TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when it compiles to JavaScript.  Answers to this question will range from "you can't do this" to "you have to add some distinguishing properties to your function types to make something like this work" and even to "you can fake this up at compile time and possibly have weird runtime errors"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. Types are erased during compilation; you cannot examine a runtime value and determine which types it was annotated with.